Is there a relationship between the concepts of a 'theory of everything' and 'intelligent design'?
I'm not sure of the relationship between them. On the one hand, intelligent design seems to suggest that there is a creator who might be in control over everything and dictate the set of rules in the universe, and a theory of everything seems to suggest that there is some theory that if you understand, it makes you omniscient.
So, is there a relationship between the concepts of a 'theory of everything' and 'intelligent design'?

I tweaked your question to avoid closure. Sometimes PhilSE is not very forgiving of new contributors and their wording. :D Feel free to roll back!

"a theory of everything seems to suggest that there is some theory that if you understand, it makes you omniscient" Why do you think this? Understanding Newton's theory of universal gravitation doesn't give you power to control gravity; understanding Maxwell's theory of electromagnetism doesn't give you power to control electricity or magnetism. Why should understanding a physical theory grant supernatural powers?

@kaya3 It doesn't give you the power to directly influence these forces with your mind, but it does very much give you the knowledge of how to manipulate the environment in order to control these forces.

Simple answer: a theory of everything has nothing to do with omniscience.
A ToE deals only with fundamental physical forces and their interactions.  It just lets us unite the fundamental forces. It wouldn't tell us anything about complex emergent phenomena like biology, consciousness, or human behavior. Knowing the rules of chess does not give you omniscient knowledge of all chess games and strategy.

While one might be tempted to think about a theory that there is scientific proof there is a God given the universe seems to obey laws, and a theory that explains all of the laws in the universe, as somehow related, they are not.
Intelligent design (ID) was an attempt by neo-creationists to pass off Biblical creationism fortified with scientific language as science. A careful reading of ID makes it clear it is a pseudoscience; and the movement's founder was very transparent about his strategy to embrace scientific doctrine to pass off Christian theology as science.
A theory of everything on the other hand has nothing to do with the supernatural or supernatural beings. It's merely a dream of some physicists to have a mathematical and philosophical framework that explains anything in the universe. Physicists will tell you that general relativity and quantum mechanics are fantastic descriptions of the universe. But they don't relate very well and there are various theorists trying to blend them and the standard model of particles.
If you believe God created the universe, and that of course is a philosophical and not a scientific question, then they are both related to what philosophers of science refer to as nomological laws. Sometimes the term 'nomological constraints' is used to describe how regularities in the universe, regularities described by scientific laws, guide our reason about what is and isn't possible in the universe, a topic in philosophy referred to as epistemic modality.
Any discussion about the relationship between the laws of the universe and God, are generally conducted in theology, as science presumes the non-existence of the supernatural in its method; such a restriction is generally referred to as methodological naturalism. Thus, strictly speaking, science and God can cohabit in a scientist's mind according to most, a situation described by the famous biologist Stephen J. Gould as NOMA.

+1 nice answer :)

@Annika Thanks. I try to see the best question in an ask. The common denominator is laws here, and I think it's fair to wonder if one is not at in their ways.  (Like me).

The two things could either exist together simultaneously, one or the other could exist, or neither could exist. They are not mutually exclusive, so they have no relationship in that way. If the universe were entirely materialistic and deterministic, it could be, in theory, possible to know all possible permutations with an adequate theory. On the other hand, if that same system existed, but contained or was influenced by an intelligent designer, then it is still possible that such a theory could exist.
The relationship is that if you did somehow have a single theory that were able to perfectly explain and describe everything, then you might be able to confirm the existence of a creator being if one exists since it might be included in such a theory. However, this is not true in the inverse in that you could not conclude the non-existence of a thing which might possibly exist outside of your scope, and you could not know that there is no scope for which you could not account. An intelligent designer might exist outside of the scope of your model, no matter how perfect your model is. Even if there actually is nothing outside of your model, you could never confirm that fact.
This comes down to the problem that you don't know what you don't know. Even if you had a model that did perfectly account for every atom or force in the observable universe, you could not know for certain that there could not be something outside of that, and you could not know that the deterministic reality you inhabit was not designed by an external intelligence. Furthermore, you could not know that there would not be states for which you cannot account. For instance, there could even be a part of "you" which extends beyond the material and which is affected by your material existence but which does not affect the material existence. So, even if there were not any intelligent designer, there could still be good reasons to believe such a thing exists.
